# make Handlebars work with an array of objects

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I have an object that I want handlebars to process

```
stock= [
{
  trailer: "TT6565",
  usual  : "Jack",
  group  : "Mercs"

},
{
  trailer: "TT6589",
  usual  : "Paul",
  group  : "Mercs"
}
]
```

This is an example, but in my script the object is created from an ajax request.

This is my handlebars script

```
<script id="mwl707" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

<div id='vehicles' class='wrapper'>
<div class='divd spacer'>&nbsp</div>

    {{#each stock}}
        <div id='{{group}}' title='Driver Details' class='divd {{group}}' >
        {{trailer}} + "<br>" + {{usual}}
        </div>
    {{/each}}

</div>

</script>

 var source = $("#mwl707").html();
 var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

 $("#thisPage").append(template( stock ));
```

The problem is the iterate(each) part does not run through my list , I think handlebars does not like objects but is there any way round this ? or have i got the code wrong ? any help please ?

Comment: Yea probably don't need the '+' unless you want those characters to be displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
{{#each this}}
    <div id='{{group}}' title='Driver Details' class='divd {{group}}' >
        {{trailer}} + "<br>" + {{usual}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

See my example: http://jsfiddle.net/svZws/

The reason you use `{{#each this}}` is because you're passing the `stock` object into the template, so in the context of the templating engine, `this` refers to your `stock` object.

If you use `{{#each stock}}`, it implies that *stock* is a property name inside the object you passed into the `template()` function.

Comment: sweetamylase: it worked fine, and thanks for your time and the explanation !

Comment: @sweetamylase 'stock' is an array of objects right? not a object uhn?

Comment: @YoniGeek Before being passed into the template, `stock` was the variable name given to the array. It is safe to describe each item in the array as a `stock` object in the context of when we iterate through it in Handlebars template.